# BASH: sed -e not allowing my variable

Tags: bash, sed

My line variable is not being accepted by my sed command :(

```
linenumber=`grep -n "$player" "$outputfile" | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\):.*$/\1/'`

sed -e "'${linenumber}'s/2013-08-25/test/"
```

my output is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use awk, it has less caveats

```
linenumber=$(awk -v p="$player" '$0 ~ p { print NR }' "$outputfile")
awk -v n="$linenumber" 'NR == n { sub(/2013-08-25/,"test") }1' "$outputfile"
```

and of course you don't need multiple steps:

```
awk -v p="$player" '$0 ~ p{ sub(/2013-08-25/,"test") }1' "$outputfile"
```

To write the output back to your input file:

```
awk 'script' "$outputfile" > tmp && mv tmp "$outputfile"
```

The above does the same thing sed does, it's just that you specify the tmp file instead of sed coming up with one for you. If you'd rather have awk do that for you then with recent gawk versions you can do:

```
awk -i inedit 'script' "$outputfile"
```

Whatever. It is NOT worth giving up awk simplicity and functionality to avoid the triviality of creating your own tmp file.

Comment: Only thing is that this isn't writing over my output file. 

my outputfile:
    Fenlig 2013-08-25 01:21:20
    Liber8or 2013-08-25 01:26:00

When I run your command it simple just outputs the whole thing but doesn't write...
    Fenlig 2013-08-25 01:21:20
    Liber8or test 01:26:00

I need to just edited the specific date in my file which is why I was using sed.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show you how to write the output back to your input file.

Answer (score 1):

The address in `sed` does not contain single quotes. Remove them. Also, you should check that `$linenumber` is a single number (i.e. neither several numbers nor empty).